# Snowflake and Databricks: Run multiple commands with Utils.runQuery

Tags: scala, azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I'm trying to use **Utils.runQuery** in Databricks to run multiple commands separated by ";" at once and it is throwing the error: *"Query executed successfully, but the first statement returned an update count (result set required)."*.

The query I'm trying to run looks like this:

```
TRUNCATE COMPANIES;
INSERT INTO COMPANIES VALUES ('QNcv3mwnHJ5w4YB4giqkWw','Company 1', 2000);
INSERT INTO COMPANIES VALUES ('QNcv3mwnHJ5w4YB4giqkWw','Company 2', 3000);
```

Any idea on how solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is that an error or a warning?  Do all of the queries execute?

Comment: Also, might be better to insert all of your values at one time, anyway.  Is there a reason you are inserting record one at a time?

Comment: It is an Exception: "SnowflakeSQLException: Query executed successfully, but the first statement returned an update count (result set required)." However the queries get executed successfully.

Comment: I have situations where I will need to execute SnowSQL files with multiple Insert/Update/Delete statements. It would be good if I could call Utils.runQuery or any other method passing the content of those files without having to worry whether there is only one or many commands